# How to use custome string with dynamic value in ionic cordovasocial sharing?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I want to use social sharing with custom text as well as dynamic content in ionic framework - android platform.
The view and the function code is below

```
<p align="center"><img src="img/share-twitter.png" width="90px" class="button" ng-click="shareViaTwitter('Today Im on {{names.name}}  Mode via Beta APP', '{{names.img}}')" />

     $scope.shareViaTwitter = function(message, image, link) {
                $cordovaSocialSharing.canShareVia("twitter", message, image, link).then(function(result) {
                    $cordovaSocialSharing.shareViaTwitter(message, image, link);
                }, function(error) {
                    alert("Cannot share on Twitter");
                });
            }
```

In the above code names.name is name ex. John. and names.img is an url ex. :http/something/1.png. The valeus are reflecting there but while clicking share button it skips the dynamic values it will come like "Today Im on   Mode via Beta APP" How to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

try this way:

```
ng-click="shareViaTwitter('Today Im on '+names.name +' Mode via Beta APP', names.img)"
```

and check in method using console what values are getting..!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issues and it worked when I moved the code to a function in the controller and called the function with `ng-click`.

```
$scope.shareTwitter = function() {
  $scope.shareMessage = 'My high score was ' +  $scope.score + '  on awesome game app!';
  window.plugins.socialsharing.shareViaTwitter($scope.shareMessage, null, 'http://example.com');
}

<button ng-click="shareTwitter();">Twitter</button>
```